# Inclusion of Collator In Parachain Lease

Tags: polkadot, parachain-collator, collator

I understand that allocating a collator node (or a few) to each chain w/a Parachain slot per era is overkill from a trust perspective. However, from a developer's perspective, it would reduce a noticeable amount of friction in launching a chain w/ Substrate.

If we're trying to reduce the friction required in launching chains on Polkadot, what would be the downside in allocating collator nodes to each parachain per era? This would allow chains to be launched w/ a trusted collator node, reduce the hassle of having to learn the networking stack related to collators for a chain that you're launching, and also streamline tokenomics for chains that reimburse collators for their job on the network.

Comment: One big one: very easy to DOS and thus stop all activities for the chain. If no other nodes exist, and the database of your collator is lost, your chain history is gone, and if recent state is lost, your chain is briked.

Comment: Remember you are launching a network, not deploying a contract. The role of a parachain is to be a provider, not to be a fire and forget/ managed by someone else affair.

Comment: Updated -- multiple collator nodes could be allocated as well. Meant this more as an architectural question vs. having a single collator node